# What do you call people in positions of power or some criminal who protect you in some way?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call people in high places or some criminal who protect you in some way? For example, if it's someone in a high place and you did something illegal, they abuse their power to help you get away with it. Or if it's a crimina they literally protect you from other criminals. I would like to know formal and informal ways to say it.

Comment: Do you mean someone who specifically is criminal, and protects another, or anyone influential? I am not aware of any generic term for such a person.  Commonly the (verb) phrases *protecting* or *giving protection to* are used. Their usage is quite general. Sometimes law enforcement *protects* an informant.

Comment: some criminal who protect**s**  you today.  Also, in a high place can be a building or tree. I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can think of are the idioms “friends in high places” or “connections”.

For instance, if there is a local crime ring that never seems to be targeted by the police (or if they are, never gets convicted), you might suspect they “have friends in high places” or are “connected”.

Both have a non-criminal sense; for instance, you might get a job because you’re connected to (known by) people at that company who are high enough up to get you hired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the best answer but it is *an* answer.

**Godfather**

> 2: one having a relation to someone or something analogous to that of
> a male sponsor to his godchild: such as a: one that founds, supports,
> or inspires made him the godfather of a whole generation of rebels —
> The Times Literary Supplement (London)
>
> b: the leader of an organized crime syndicate
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/godfather

[image]
https://moddroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/The-Godfather-.png

Comment: *Godfather* is not a generic word for someone who meets the criteria of the question, but rather, at best, one used by a relatively small number of specific organizations.